# css / javascript input field filling from right

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I have an HTML input field that will accept numbers, formatted to be filled from the right like in Libre Office Calc ? (or excell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
input{ 
    text-align:right; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using inline styles:

```
<input type="text" style="text-align: right"/>
```

or, put it in a style sheet, like so:

```
<style>
  .rightJustified {
      text-align: right;
  }
</style>
```

and reference the class:

```
<input type="text" class="rightJustified"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/wiwajisa/1/edit)

HTML:

`<input type="number">`

CSS:

```
input[type=number]{

    direction:rtl;
}
```